# Create stripe like button on PayPal

Tags: paypal

I do not want to redirect my customers to PayPal website for making payment. I love the way Stripe takes credit card number via popup. https://thenextweb.com/dd/2012/10/10/the-new-pay-with-stripe-button-makes-online-payments-not-feel-like-death/

How can I do the similar thing with PayPal?

Comment: Have you read the paypal API/docs, to see if they offer something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are talking about an in-context experience using light box -
- Use the new PayPal button. Try it out here

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client